# Gyrator add horizontal separation between ports

Tags: circuitikz

Is there any way to add a horizontal space between the two circles of the gyrator?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw(0,0) 
    node[gyrator] (G) {}
 (G.A1) node[anchor=east] {A1}
 (G.A2) node[anchor=east] {A2}
 (G.B1) node[anchor=west] {B1}
 (G.B2) node[anchor=west] {B2}
 (G.base) node{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]
I would like to draw this

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the properties of the component which is defined in `pgfcircquadpoles.tex`. This is an example for adding a space of 1cm. The variable `\Space` is defined for the increasing the space. The trick is to shift the right part of the component to the right by `\Space`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[]{circuitikz}

\def\Space{1cm}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclarequadpole{gyrator}{

    \def\stretto{.4}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\stretto\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\stretto\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\Space+\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\Space+\stretto\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\Space+\stretto\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\Space+\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}

    \pgfusepath{draw}

    \pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\stretto\pgf@circ@res@left}{.7*\stretto\pgf@circ@res@down}}
    \pgfpatharc{90}{270}{.7*\stretto\pgf@circ@res@down}

    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\Space+\stretto\pgf@circ@res@right}{.7*\stretto\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{.7*\stretto\pgf@circ@res@down}
    \pgfusepath{draw}

}{}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} 
\draw(0,0) 
    node[gyrator] (G) {}
 (G.A1) node[anchor=east] {A1}
 (G.A2) node[anchor=east] {A2}
 (G.B1) node[anchor=west,xshift=\Space] {B1}
 (G.B2) node[anchor=west,xshift=\Space] {B2}
 (G.base) node{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```